# Swift 3 macOS, set default button style

Tags: swift, macos, nsbutton

When I create a new `NSButton`, how can I set it's style to the Default one?

```
let (nomplusbut) = NSButton(frame: CGRect(x: 200, y: iy, width: 300, height: 40))
(nomplusbut).title = "Pfad öffnen..."
(nomplusbut).target = (self, action: #selector(buttonAction)) as AnyObject?
(nomplusbut).isBordered = true
(nomplusbut).setButtonType(NSMomentaryPushInButton)

arraybut.append(nomplusbut)

print(array[array.count - 1].stringValue)
self.view.addSubview(arraybut[arraybut.count - 1])
```

Style I want to have:

[image: button with default style]

Current Style:

[image: button with current style]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change the button's `bezelStyle` to `rounded`, e.g.:

```
nomplusbut.bezelStyle = .rounded
```